# Continuous function on product of metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and suppose $k: X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$.

A paper I am reading says that "$k(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a continuous function". However, I am not familiar with continuity of multivariate functions on products of metric spaces. Does this mean that $k$ is continuous with respect to the [product metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric)

$$
d^*((x_0,x_1), (x'_0, x'_1)) = \sqrt{d(x_0,x'_0)^2 + d(x_1, x'_1)^2},
$$

so that

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0,\; \exists \delta > 0,\;
d^*((x_0,x_1), (x'_0, x'_1)) < \delta \implies |k(x_0,x_1) - k(x'_0,x'_1)| < \epsilon\,?
$$

If this interpretation is correct, is there a canonical textbook reference that anyone can recommend which clarifies this particular construction?

Comment: how is $k$ defined? continuity depends on that

Comment: Typically the metric would be the product metric as you have denoted above. Any of the usual equivalent metrics would work as well , such as $d^*(x,y) = \max(d(x_1,y_1), d(x_2,y_2))$.

Comment: @janmarqz I think the _definition_ of continuity should be independent of the particular choice of $k$, but we can take $k(x,x') = \exp(-d(x,x'))$ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is that *the product of metric spaces is a metric space* (like the product of vector spaces is a vector space, and the product of groups is a group, etc).  The definition of "product of metric spaces" must specify how the Cartesian product of the underlying sets is equipped with a metric. A typical choice is the product metric you mentioned, e.g., 
 [Prove that the product space is a metric space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052511/prove-that-the-product-space-is-a-metric-space)

It's true that there are other natural choices such as 
$$d_1((x_0,x_1), (x'_0, x'_1)) =  d(x_0,x'_0) + d(x_1, x'_1)$$
and
$$d_\infty((x_0,x_1), (x'_0, x'_1)) = \max( d(x_0,x'_0), d(x_1, x'_1))$$
It's easy to see that the metrics they define on the product are comparable to $d^*$: 
$$
d_\infty \le d^* \le d_1 \le 2d_\infty \tag1
$$
In particular, they induce the same topology but (1) is much stronger than that: this kind of equivalence (bi-Lipschitz equivalence)  preserves most of the metric structure beyond topology (completeness, Lipschitz functions, Hausdorff dimension, etc).

The point being, the metric structure of product space is a thing to establish first. Then there is no need to discuss "continuity of multivariate functions on products of metric spaces";  the continuity is just regular continuity on the metric space $X\times Y$.

Since you asked for references, here is one:  "A Course in Metric Geometry" by Burago, Burago, Ivanov.