# The Euclidean metric satisfies triangle inequality in cross product of two metric spaces $X$ and $Y.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $X \times Y$ for metric spaces $X$ and $Y.$

I'm trying to show that $d_E(p,q) = \sqrt{d_X(p,q)^2 + d_Y(p,q)^2}$ fulfills the triangle inequality, but I can't workout the algebra so that things fall into place and it is clear that $$d_E(p_1,p_3) \leq d_E(p_1,p_2) + d_E(p_2,p_3).$$

I avoided writing out everything that I have written on paper because it is messy, but here is a little bit:

Consider $$d_E(p,p'') = \sqrt{d_X(p,p'')^2 + d_Y(p,p'')^2}$$ and $$d_E(p,p') = \sqrt{d_X(p,p')^2 + d_Y(p,p')^2}$$ and $$d_E(p',p'') = \sqrt{d_X(p',p'')^2 + d_Y(p',p'')^2}.$$ 
        It must be shown that $$d_E(p,p'') \leq d_E(p,p') + d_E(p',p''),$$ or that $$d_E(p,p'')^2 \leq (d_E(p,p') + d_E(p',p''))^2.$$

I then proceeded to expand it out via the square, and it became messy and not, in the end, clear that the left was less than or equal to the right.

Comment: What you have doesn't make sense to start with.  Is $p\in X$?  Is $p\in Y$?  Is $p\in X\times Y$?  If $X$ and $Y$ are different metric spaces how can $p$ and $q$ be in both to measure their distance?

Comment: Sorry. Let me make an edit.

Comment: I see your point. I suppose I was considering as a model for visualization R^2. Then, would not $d_X(p,p)$ just be the distance between the points considering only the x-axis?

Comment: I will copy verbatim from the book: Define a metric on the Cartesian product $M = X \times Y$ of two metric spaces $X$ and $Y.$ Consider the metric $d_E(p,p') = \sqrt{d_X(x,x')^2+d_Y(y,y')^2},$ where $p = (x,y)$ and $p' = (x',y')$ belong to $M.$ I realize that what I wrote is ambiguous, but what i mean by $d_X(p,p')$ is $d_X(p_X,p'_X).$

Comment: That is, the distance in $X$ of the $X$ components of $p$ and $p'.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052511/prove-that-the-product-space-is-a-metric-space

Comment: In essence it's the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $d_X(x_1,x_3)≤d_X(x_1,x_2)+d_X(x_2,x_3)$ and $d_Y(y_1,y_3)≤d_Y(y_1,y_2)+d_Y(y_2,y_3)$. Let us put $r_1=d_X(x_1,x_2),s_1=d_X(x_2,x_3),r_2=d_Y(y_1,y_2),s_2=d_Y(y_2,y_3)$.

Note that, $[(r_1+s_1)^2+(r_2+s_2)^2]^\frac{1}{2}≤(r_1^2+r_2^2)^\frac{1}{2}+(s_1^2+s_2^2)^\frac{1}{2}$(expand both sides to reduce shorter form and then apply cauchy-schwarz). Hence $d_E((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3))≤[(d_X(x_1,x_2))^2+(d_Y(y_1,y_2))^2]^\frac{1}{2} +[(d_X(x_2,x_3))^2+(d_Y(y_2,y_3))^2]^\frac{1}{2}=d_E((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))+d_E((x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3))$.